# Converse of theorem: if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent.

Tags: probability-theory, independence

I know the following result:

Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be independent. Suppose that $g_1,\ldots, g_n$ are Borel measurable functions from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and for each $i$, let $Y_i = g_i(X_i)$. Then $Y_1,\ldots, Y_n$ are independent.

But when is the converse true? If $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent, then when is it true that $X$ and $Y$ are independent? Is it not true in general and we need to find counterexamples?

Comment: Not true in general; counterexample by choosing $f$ or $g$ or both constant

Comment: It’s true if $f,g$ are injective, cause then you can invert them

Comment: Thank you both!